# jQuery select all checkboxes, if checkbox is already checked don't .change()

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5msp5jbn/1/)**

When you check one of the boxes, the corresponding table cells have their text removed and placed in an input text value. The issue is with the select all function because it doesn't trigger the .change() event correctly. If you check a box and then check the "select all" checkbox, it clears out the cell values. How can I determine if it is already checked, to not do the .change() function?

```
$("#selectall").click(function () {
var checkall = $("#selectall").prop('checked');

if (checkall) {

    $('#amazon-update :checkbox').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.is(':checked')) {
            //nothing
        } else {
            $(".checkbox").prop("checked", true).change();
        }
    });

} else {

    $('#amazon-update :checkbox').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.is(':checked')) {
            $(".checkbox").prop("checked", false).change();
        } else {
            //nothing                           
        }
    });
}
});

$(".checkbox").click(function () {

if ($(".checkbox").length == $(".checkbox:checked").length) {
    $("#selectall").prop("checked", true);

} else {
    $("#selectall").prop("checked", false);
}
});

$('#amazon-update :checkbox').change(function () {

var $this = $(this);

// $this will contain a reference to the checkbox

if ($this.is(':checked')) {

    // the checkbox was checked
    var sku_td = $this.parent().siblings('.sku').text();
    var price_td = $this.parent().siblings('.price').text();
    var quantity_td = $this.parent().siblings('.quantity').text();

    $this.parent().siblings('.price').empty();
    $this.parent().siblings('.quantity').empty();

    var sku = $('<input type="hidden" name="sku[]" value="' + sku_td + '">');
    var price = $('<input type="text" class="form-control" name="price[]" value="' + price_td + '">');
    var quantity = $('<input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity[]" value="' + quantity_td + '">');

    $this.parent().siblings('.sku').append(sku);
    $this.parent().siblings('.price').append(price);
    $this.parent().siblings('.quantity').append(quantity);
} else {

    // the checkbox was unchecked           
    var sku_td = $this.parent().siblings('.sku').children().val();
    var price_td = $this.parent().siblings('.price').children().val();
    var quantity_td = $this.parent().siblings('.quantity').children().val();

    $this.parent().siblings('.sku').empty();
    $this.parent().siblings('.price').empty();
    $this.parent().siblings('.quantity').empty();

    $this.parent().siblings('.sku').append(sku_td);
    $this.parent().siblings('.price').append(price_td);
    $this.parent().siblings('.quantity').append(quantity_td);

}

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the code for you on fiddle.

The main problem is with this line:

```
 $(".checkbox").prop("checked", true).change();
```

Instead of this line it should be:

$this.prop("checked", true).change().

Please refer update fiddler.

http://jsfiddle.net/5msp5jbn/6/

Comment: True, it happens the solution is right there and we just cannot see.